# How Can I nest in Gutenberg Richtext multiline list block

Tags: wordpress, html-lists, wordpress-gutenberg, richtext

I build Custom block type by using WordPress Gutenberg.

As core/list block , I want to nest list tag.
My ideal output is like bellow.

```html
<ul>
  <li>list1</li>
  <li><ul>
      <li>nested list1</li>
      <li>nested list3</li>
      </ul>
</ul>
```

My Code is like this.

Can RichText nest or have child?

```
<RichText
        style={{marginBottom:mb}}
        tagName="ul"
        value={ lists }
        onChange={  (value) => {
            setAttributes({ lists: value})
        } }
        multiline="li"
        formattingControls={[]}
/>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The core WordPress Gutenberg [List Block](https://wordpress.org/support/article/list-block/) already supports for multilevel/nested lists like you are trying to make.

If you would like to create your own similiar block, the [source code of the List Block](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/list/edit.js) is a great place to start to see how it uses `<RichText/>`. No child blocks are added to `<RichText/>`, instead it calls a function that formats then returns the list contents with/without indentation. The content is then saved as markup, eg `<ul><li>..</li></ul>` in the [blocks attributes](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/list/block.json) as *values* and the source is html, enabling the list to be re-edited by `<RichText/>`.